# Unable to access System Small Caps Font

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, uifont

I am getting the system small caps font using:

```
    let systemFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0, weight: UIFont.Weight.regular)
    
    let smallCapsDesc = systemFont.fontDescriptor.addingAttributes([
        UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName.featureSettings: [
            [
                UIFontDescriptor.FeatureKey.featureIdentifier: kLowerCaseType,
                UIFontDescriptor.FeatureKey.typeIdentifier: kUpperCaseSmallCapsSelector
            ]
        ]
    ])
    let smallCapsFont = UIFont(descriptor: smallCapsDesc, size: systemFont.pointSize)
    let smallCapsAttrbs: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key.font : smallCapsFont]

    text.setAttributes(smallCapsAttrbs, range: NSRange(location: start, length: length))
```

and am receiving this error.

> CoreText note: Client requested name ".SFUI-Regular", it will get
> TimesNewRomanPSMT rather than the intended font. All system UI font
> access should be through proper APIs such as
> CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage() or +[UIFont systemFontOfSize:].

I am unsure of any other way to get the smallCaps version of the `San Francisco` font. How do I do this?

Comment: You may want to take a look at this extension: https://gist.github.com/HarshilShah/5df56b511acdfb895cfce001d1728620

Comment: @DonMag that extension is unfortunately causing the same error.

Comment: hmm... I'm not seeing the result you're getting. I'm assuming `text` is a `NSMutableAttributedString`? Maybe try it like this:   https://pastebin.com/qGuZ78YW